# Functional Programming Idiom to compute maximum of 4 numbers without mutation in racket/haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have a count of the number of occurrences of four characters in a string in 4 variables a, b, c and d.

Now, I want to know which character occurs the maximum number of times.

I want a functional programming idiom to solve this problem.

One way to solve it in Haskell is as follows -

```
foldl (\(count1, char1) (count2, char2) -> if count1 > count2 then (count1, char1) else (count2, char2)) (a, "A")  (zip [b, c, d] ["B", "C", "D"])
```

Does someone have other functional programming idioms for this problem?

Comment: sort, group, maximum?

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell, the idiomatic way would be to use `maximumBy`:

```hs
Data.List Data.Ord> snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) $ zip [4,3,7,1] "abcd"
'c'
```

Comment: To put this in idiomatic association list form, and introduce the `on` combinator, use ``fst . maximumBy (compare `on` snd)``.

Comment: Incidentally, `maximum` here would work as well, and further guarantee that on a tie the largest char would be taken. If we want to be extremely pedantic, `maximumBy` is undefined on a tie since its documentation requires "The function is assumed to define a total ordering." -- this requirement is way too much restrictive for my tastes, and I guess most Haskellers would ignore it since the actual implementation does not need it.

Comment: @chi `comparing fst` is a total ordering. Total orders are allowed to declare two values equal.

Comment: @DanielWagner Uhm, but `comparing fst (2, 'a') (2, 'b')` gives `EQ`. I would consider it as a preorder, but not a partial order, hence not a total order.

Comment: @chi From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order): a total order is "transitive, antisymmetric, and total". Which of these properties are you claiming is not satisfied by `comparing fst` (using "returns `LT` or `EQ`" as a proxy for `<=` and using "returns `EQ`" as a proxy for `=`)?

Comment: @DanielWagner The usage of "returning `EQ`" as a proxy for `=` is not so evident from the docs. And in this specific example, it's hard for me to say that `(2,'a')` and `(2,'b')` are "equal". If you quotient the ordering in that way, it does become a total order. Perhaps your reading of the docs is the intended/correct one, but I find the docs quite unclear on that. I mean, how should library functions behave when `.. = EQ` is only an equivalence? Could e.g. `sortBy comp [1..3]` return `[1,3,3]` if `comp 2 3 = EQ`? Could `maximumBy (comparing fst) [(2,'a')] = (2,'b')`? (parametricity aside)

Comment: @chi Why would we set aside parametricity?